# ViewController's presentingViewController being set wrong?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

If ViewControllerA is embeded in a navigationController , and ViewControllerB is presented Modally by ViewControllerA .

when I print the ViewControllerB's presentingViewController property , i found the presentingViewController is point to the navigation controller , not the ViewControllerA.

But i think if the presentingViewController point to  ViewControllerA more reasonable.

Comment: That happens because viewController A is embedded **inside** a `UINavigationController`

Comment: but based on the presentingViewController documention , it just state that "When you present a view controller modally (either explicitly or implicitly) using the presentViewController:animated:completion: method, the view controller that was presented has this property set to the view controller that presented it"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> But i think if the presentingViewController point to ViewControllerA more reasonable

The thing is that it doesn't matter what you think is reasonable. What you see is how it in fact works. Your job is to accept and understand it, not to disagree with it.

The navigation controller is the presenting view controller because it is the root view controller. This is a fullscreen presentation, so the navigation controller is the view controller whose view is replaced by the presented view controller's view.

And in fact, your `present` sent to view controller A *is passed along* to the containing navigation controller. You are allowed to tell view controller A to `present` only as a kind of convenience.

View controller A is called by Apple the "source" view controller, because it is the view controller to which `present` was sent, but there is no way to learn that from talking to view controller B.

(You might want to read [this section of my online book](http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch19.html#_presented_view_controller), starting with the sentence, "The presenting view controller ... is not necessarily the view controller to which you sent `presentViewController:animated:completion:`." In my book, I call the source view controller the *original presenter*.)

Comment: thanks @matt , now i understand , the presentingViewController may not be  the same as source controller

Comment: Is there a workaround for this bug/behavior?

Comment: @internetdotcom It's good, not bad. There are two things to be distinguished and the system does indeed distinguish them.